# Trying to get property 'Url' of non-object (View: D:\XAMPP71\htdocs\website-ikan\resources\views\gizi\listproduct.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, one-to-one

I have a problem with making model for one to one relationship. this is my code for the page

```
<div class="col-sm-8 container">
            <div class="row">
                @foreach ($ikan as $i)
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10 offset-md-0 offset-sm-1" onclick="location.href='/';">
                    <div class="card"> <div class="container-gambar" style="aspect-ratio: 3/2;"><img class="card-img-top w-100 h-100" style="object-fit: contain" src="{{$i->fotos->Url}}"></div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h6 class="font-weight-bold pt-1">{{$i->nama_ikan}}</h6>
                            <div class="text-muted description">Space for small product description</div>
                                <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                    <div class="h6 font-weight-bold">{{$i->hargas->harga}}</div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my code for the models :
<?php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\HargaIkan;

class Ikan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "ikan";

    public function fotos(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\FotoIkan', 'ikan_id');
    }

    public function hargas(){
        return $this->hasOne(HargaIkan::class, 'ikan_id');
    }
}
```

this is also my code for the other model :
<?php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Ikan;

class HargaIkan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "harga_ikan";

    public function ikans(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Ikan::class, 'ikan_id');
    }
}
```

and this is the another one :
<?php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FotoIkan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "foto_ikan";

    public function ikans(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Ikan', 'ikan_id')->withDefault([
            'harga' => 'Tidak diketahui',
        ]);
    }
}
```

and this is my controller :

```
public function listprodukgizi(){
        $ikan = Ikan::all();

        return view('gizi.listproduct', ['ikan'=>$ikan]);
    }
```

Do you have any solution for this? i checked my database and the name for the columns is right. I also check the result for the relation of each array and it doesnt have relation.

Comment: (1) Did you check if the $i has fotos. Try ```dd($i->fotos)``` to see what is it. (2) Did you try with array syntax like ```$i->fotos['Url']```

Comment: is your field `Url` with a capital `U` or `url` ?

Comment: You language may be different, but a hasOne relationship should have a singular name (foto). You should eager load the foto.  `$ikan = Ikan::with('foto')->get();`

Comment: @N69S with capital, i already checked for that

Comment: @Snapey i did but it didn't work

Comment: @Bulent i did, but it throw another error
Trying to access array offset on value of type null (View: D:\XAMPP71\htdocs\website-ikan\resources\views\gizi\listproduct.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

```
{{$i->fotos->Url}}
```

you have to code defensively.  What if one of $i does not have a foto?  You should be prepared for foto to be null

easiest to avoid error is with the null coalesce operator

```
{{$i->fotos->Url ?? 'NO FOTO'}}
```

change NO FOTO to whatever you want to do when Ikan does not have foto